# Xcode4 UML plugin?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, uml, xcode4

I want to design my classes in UML. Currently am using ArgoUML, which is free, but not well integrated with Mac OS X, to say the least :-)

Googling around there's not much information

- any plugin/extension of XCode4 to do UML, like in Eclipse?
- third party apps that look well in Mac?
- any chance to get two ways code generation? Asking for too much? :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my [list of UML tools](http://modeling-languages.com/content/uml-tools) I don't have many Mac-specific tools. [CanvasUML](http://www.ditchnet.org/canvasuml/) (free, only class diagrams) and [MacA&D](http://www.excelsoftware.com/maca&dproducts.html) are the only completely designed for Mac. Others like VisualParadigm and MagicDraw have also a MAC version of their products

Comment: Good list! There's not much to pick of. I'll stick with ArgoUML, which is better than BOUML & Violet. Just ugly :-)